# Can I ask for recommendations for software that's intended as an example (think "hello world" of technology)?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking into learning more about specific technology, so I'd like to find some simple implementation of it that, while not feature-rich, can be read by somewhat unprepared person. Is question about this on-topic here?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the software so you can read the source code and learn (can be a great way to learn!); is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes, that was my exact idea. I've actually found an answer for my specific case on SO, but I'm still curious if this would fit this site better/as well.